# Facebook Developer login error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was working with a developer on Facebook integration with my iOS app and he used his Facebook developer account. Now, I switched over to my Facebook developer account and changed the App ID in the .plist. I am able to login through Facebook in my app, but when I try to publish a post to Facebook, I am asked to login again. When I enter my Facebook login credentials, I get the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x178477840 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x17846a8c0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:InlineLoginCancelled

If I use the previous App ID from his Facebook developer account, it works perfectly and the post publishes to Facebook without even asking for credentials again. Also, this is odd because the new App ID does work on Android, just not on iOS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this error previously due to having a bad or old token from doing something similar where I had multiple Facebook apps hooked up to the same iOS App. Your device is likely still trying to sign in with a previous token, which is no longer valid as you have changed your app settings.

Try the following:

1. Deleting the app from your Facebook account. Log in into facebook > Settings > Apps > delete your app.
2. Sign out of your Facebook app on your device (and in your iPhone/iPad settings if you have it integrated there).
3. Kill your app completely and then try again.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean deleting the app from the **old** Facebook Developer account?

Comment: No, i mean delete your app from the your personal facebook account. As that facebook user has accepted permissions from the old app.

Comment: It still does not seem to be working. Would I need to incorporate the new access token within the iOS code?